# Getting logs/more information during start-build command execution

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise

Jenkins pipeline is building Docker images. OpenShift plugin(s) are used for the same.

An example command:

```
openshift.selector(BUILD_CONFIG_NAME, "${appBcName}").startBuild("--from-dir=${artifactPath}", '--wait','--follow')
```

While this works smoothly most of the time, whenever this command fails due to some underlying platform issues, almost no information is seen in the Jenkins build job console:

```
[Pipeline] }
[start-build:buildconfig/amld5-car-reporting-spacetime-ubi-openshift-java-runtimejd] ............................................................
[start-build:buildconfig/amld5-car-reporting-spacetime-ubi-openshift-java-runtimejd] Uploading finished
[start-build:buildconfig/amld5-car-reporting-spacetime-ubi-openshift-java-runtimejd] Error from server (BadRequest): unable to wait for build amld5-car-reporting-spacetime-ubi-openshift-java-runtimejd-857 to run: timed out waiting for the condition
[Pipeline] }
ERROR: Error running start-build on at least one item: [buildconfig/amld5-car-reporting-spacetime-ubi-openshift-java-runtimejd];
{err=, verb=start-build, cmd=oc --server=https://api.scp-west-zone02-z01.net:6443 --certificate-authority=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt --namespace=sb-1166-amld5-car-service-se --token=XXXXX start-build buildconfig/amld5-car-reporting-spacetime-ubi-openshift-java-runtimejd --from-dir=./build/libs --wait --follow -o=name , out=Uploading directory "build/libs" as binary input for the build ...
............................................................
Uploading finished
Error from server (BadRequest): unable to wait for build amld5-car-reporting-spacetime-ubi-openshift-java-runtimejd-857 to run: timed out waiting for the condition
, status=1}

[Pipeline] // catchError
```

I need more verbosity, detailed error information. I checked the [start-build command reference](https://docs.openshift.com/dedicated/3/cli_reference/basic_cli_operations.html#start-build), and I thought `--build-loglevel [0-5]` might help here. When I used it, I got a warning that since I am using source type as 'Binary' in the BuildConfig, logging isn't supported(seriously???)
NOTE: the selector returned when -F/--follow is supplied to startBuild() will be inoperative for the various selector operations.
Consider removing those options from startBuild and using the logs() command to follow the build output.

```
[start-build:buildconfig/casc-docs-spacetime-ubi-openshift-java-runtimeadoptopenjdk] WARNING: Specifying --build-loglevel with binary builds is not supported.
[start-build:buildconfig/casc-docs-spacetime-ubi-openshift-java-runtimeadoptopenjdk] WARNING: Specifying environment variables with binary builds is not supported.
[start-build:buildconfig/casc-docs-spacetime-ubi-openshift-java-runtimeadoptopenjdk] Uploading directory "build/libs" as binary input for the build ...
[start-build:buildconfig/casc-docs-spacetime-ubi-openshift-java-runtimeadoptopenjdk] ..
```

How do I get more logs, info. while executing the start-build command?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem, I just used something like:

```
def build = openshift.selector(BUILD_CONFIG_NAME, "${appBcName}").startBuild("--from-dir=${artifactPath}", '--wait','--follow')
build.logs('-f')
```

And so far it seems to work, I got the logs from my openshift build in my Jenkins pipeline. Now I'll try to get the logs only if build does not Complete, to reduce the overall logs.

(for future searchers like me ^^)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to openshift console and check the logs from there. But I think this problem often happens if your openshift project is short of allocated resources either the CPU or RAM. Get it increased and the problem may be resolved